# Automatically recycle contents of Desktop in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, automation, desktop

is it possible to automatically move the entire content of the Desktop folder into Recycle Bin every day or other time period? Or maybe automatically recycle all files/folders older than say, a week?

I want to keep my desktop as clean as possible and only use it as temporary storage anyway, and now I spend quite a lot of time just `Ctrl+A`ing and `Delete`ing when organizing my desktop.

Thank you!

Comment: As a desktop is only a usuall folder, you can surely write a simple batch file like cd C:\User\me\Desktop and del *. This script can be executed via windows scheduler for example. Is that what you want?

Comment: @duDE Deleting from the command line doesn't seem to move the files to the recycle bin.

Comment: Well, move C:\Users\Me\Desktop\\* "C:\$Recycle.bin" then ;)

Comment: Are you trying to delete all files or shortcuts too?

Comment: All files and shortcuts; and I'm looking into Windows batch scripting right now :)